# Need less restrictive json parser

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, knockout.js

I need to pass different strings formatted as json to a json parser.

Problem is that jQuery.parseJSON() and JSON.parse() only support a very strict json format:

> Passing in a malformed JSON string may result in an exception being thrown. For example, the following are all malformed JSON strings:
>
> {test: 1} (test does not have double quotes around it).
>
> {'test': 1} ('test' is using single quotes instead of double quotes).

Is there a less restrictive parser that will allow passing values like that (without quotes or with single quote)?

BTW, I'm using KO 2.2.1 so if it has something like that it would be helpful.

Comment: Sounds like you're not parsing JSON at all.

Comment: I'm getting the values from html `data-*` attr which are written by many developers and mistake are bound to happen, so i'm looking for a way to make it easier. It is a json structure, the only difference is that it has no quotes or single quote on the key properties.

Comment: If the structure isn't too complex, you could quite easily write your own to your own specs...

Comment: @ftom2 : you need to convert your data first into an object format and then you can stringify it by JSON.stringify(your_data_obj) and finally you can able to use JSON.parse

Comment: @MohitPandey - the data is in object format: `{somekey:someval}`, the problem is with the quotes that have to be in certain way.

Comment: @ftom2 : If its already in object format,then i don't think JSON.stringify({someKey:1}) will yield a bug.

Comment: @MohitPandey - You got it all wrong, i need to make an Object from a string, not the opposite.

Comment: @MohitPandey If you've already converted your data into object format, what's the point of roundtripping through JSON again?

Comment: @Tomer please consider changing the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as a less strict JSON parser. You're either dealing with well-formed JSON, or you're not dealing with JSON at all. To parse your custom format, you may want to take a look at [Crockford's parser](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) source code, and modify it to fit your needs.

Or, for a quick and dirty solution you might just use [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) (but be aware [its use has security implications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don.27t_use_eval.21)).

Comment: By 'less strict' I don't mean not in json format, I only mean the quote are not that important. like when creating a js object, you can choose to omit or put the quotes on the key.

Comment: JS accepts that, but JSON doesn't. If you don't add the quotes, you don't have JSON, you have something similar. The JSON parsers are all built to parse actual JSON. Also, see my edit, `eval` would probably work, but should be used with care.

Comment: I think there are instances where it would be nice to have a less-strict parser. For example, strict parsers don't allow trailing commas on the last element of an array or dictionary entry. Would be nice to have something that isn't that strict.

Answer (score 2):

There is a node module called [jsonic](https://github.com/rjrodger/jsonic) that parses non strict JSON.

```
npm install jsonic
```

You might also use eval:

```
var parsed = eval(json)
```

Be careful because `eval` could also run code so you must be sure that you know what you are parsing.

Comment: This is the correct answer, as opposed to all of the sanctimonious replies.  I have successfully parsed invalid json found at https://github.com/infobloxopen/infoblox-swagger-wapi/tree/master/infoblox-swagger-ui/dist/v2.11 by tweaking jsonic.js to allow for case-insensitive literals (see https://github.com/jsonicjs/jsonic/pull/29).